# How do I upload a PDF for users to download?

Tags: 8, navigation, files

I am very new to Drupal. I simply want to provide a link in an article for users to download a pdf document. How do I upload the document on the admin side and then link to it in an article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy, in `admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields` **make file field** like so:

[image: mange fields]

All other stuff is logical:

[image: article-> manage fields]

Don't forget to put PDF as an allowed extensions:

[image: allowed file extensions]